# Helm upgrade fails on new subchart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Helm is failing when upgrading a chart that contains a new sub-chart

e.g.:

```
chart
    /templates
    /charts
        /sub-1
    values.yaml
```

Now this chart get's updated, and a new sub-chart is added, which contains a configmap etc..

```
chart
    /templates
    /charts
        /sub-1
        /sub-2
            /templates
                configmap.yaml #config
    values.yaml
```

When we run `helm upgrade <release> <chart> --install` we keep getting:

`Error: UPGRADE FAILED: no ConfigMap with the name "config" found`

My guess is that helms tries to diff it with the 'previous' version of `config` but it does not yet exist. And thus the error. However, how could I make this work without deleting and re-installing the chart. This is not optimal for production scerarios.

Comment: Did you tried with `--force ` flag?

Comment: @RVandersteen One possible reason can be that the config map is used before being created itself. Can you check  and confirm that is not the case.

Comment: @Emruz Hossain In a production scenario using force shouldn't be encouraged. We don't know what the repercussions can be.

Comment: I did try with the --force and then it works - but as @AnanthuRV says it might not be a good idea.

Comment: @AnanthuRV Double checked and it is not the case

Comment: @RVandersteen is it possible to paste the sanitized version of the chart you have used?

Comment: @RVandersteen i have tried the smae thing but for me it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a blank ConfigMap in whichever Kubernetes namespace you are installing your Chart.

```
$ kubectl -n <namespace> create cm config
```

If for reason it complains about the `data` field or another field not being available you can always create a dummy one:

```
$ kubectl -n <namespace> edit cm config
```

or

```
$ kubectl -n <namespace> patch cm config -p '{"data": {"dummy": "dummy1"}}'
```

Comment: This might be the way to go in the end, would've hoped for a non manual intervention but except `--force` i don't see a solution.